# In GitLab CI, is there a variable for a Merge Request's target branch?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In my pipeline, I'd like to have a job run only if the Merge Requests target branch is a certain branch, say master or release.

Is this possible?

I've read through https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/ and unless I missed something, I'm not seeing anything that can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gitlab CI is agnostic of Merge Requests (for now). Since the pipeline runs on the origin branch you will not be able to retrieve the destination.

Answer (score 30):

*Update: 2019-03-21*

GitLab has variables for merge request info since version 11.6 (https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/ see the variables start with `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_`). But, **these variables are only available in `merge request pipelines`.**(https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/merge_request_pipelines/index.html)

To configure a CI job for merge requests, we have to set:

```
only: 
  - merge_requests
```

And then we can use `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_*` variables in those jobs.

The biggest pitfall here is **`only: merge_request` has complete different behavior from normal `only/except` parameters.**

usual `only/except` parameters:
(https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#onlyexcept-basic)

> 1. `only` defines the names of branches and tags for which the job will run.
> 2. `except` defines the names of branches and tags for which the job will not run.

`only: merge_request`: (https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/merge_request_pipelines/index.html#excluding-certain-jobs)

> The behavior of the `only: merge_requests` parameter is such that only jobs with that parameter are run in the context of a merge request; no other jobs will be run.

I felt hard to reorganize jobs to make them work like before with `only: merge_request` exists on any job. Thus I'm still using the one-liner in my original answer to get MR info in a CI job.

---

*Original answer:*

No.

But GitLab have a plan for this feature in 2019 Q2: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23902#final-assumptions

Currently, we can use a workaround to achieve this. The method is as Rekovni's answer described, and it actually works.

There's a simple one-liner, get the target branch of an MR from the current branch:

```
script: # in any script section of gitlab-ci.yml
  - 'CI_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME=$(curl -LsS -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $AWESOME_GITLAB_API_TOKEN" "https://my.gitlab-instance.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests?source_branch=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" | jq --raw-output ".[0].target_branch")'
```

Explanation:

`CI_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME` is a newly defined variable which stores resolved target branch name. Defining a variable is not necessary for various usage.

`AWESOME_GITLAB_API_TOKEN` is the variable configured in repository's CI/CD variable config. It is a GitLab personal access token(created in User Settings) with `api` scope.

About `curl` options: `-L` makes curl aware of HTTP redirections. `-sS` makes curl silent(`-s`) but show(`-S`) errors. `-H` specifies authority info accessing GitLab API.

The used API could be founded in https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/merge_requests.html#list-project-merge-requests. We use the `source_branch` attribute to figure out which MR current pipeline is running on. Thus, if a source branch has multiple MR to different target branch, you may want to change the part after `|` and do your own logic.

About `jq`(https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), it's a simple CLI util to deal with JSON stuff(what GitLab API returns). You could use `node -p` or any method you want.

Comment: How would you then use that to decide whether to conditionally run the script or not?

Answer (score 20):

Because of the [new env variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) in 11.6 `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` and `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME` jobs can be included or excluded based on the source or target branch.

Using the [only and except (complex)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyvariables-and-exceptvariables) expressions, we can build a rule to filter merge requests. For a couple examples:

**Merge request where the target branch is `master`:**

```
only:
    refs:
        - merge_requests
    variables:
        - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"
```

**Merge request except if the source branch is `master` *or* `release`:**

```
only:
    - merge_requests
except:
    variables:
        - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "master"
        - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "release"
```

If you want to use multiple refs (let's say merge_requests and tags) and multiple variables, the refs will be OR'd, [the variables will be OR'd](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#variables-expressions), and [the result will be AND'd](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only-and-except-complex):

> If any of the conditions in variables evaluates to truth when using only, a new job is going to be created. If any of the expressions evaluates to truth when except is being used, a job is not going to be created.
>
> If you use multiple keys under only or except, they act as an AND. The logic is:
>
> ```
> (any of refs) AND (any of variables) AND (any of changes) AND (if kubernetes is active)
> ```

Variable expressions are also quite primitive, only supporting equality and (basic) regex. Because the variables will be OR'd you cannot specify both a source and target branch as of gitlab 11.6, just one or the other.

Answer (score 7):

As of GitLab 11.6, there is [`CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/).

Answer (score 3):

If this is what you're really after, there could be an extremely convoluted way (untested) you could achieve this using the [merge request API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html) and [CI variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/).

With a workflow / build step something like:

1. Create merge request from `feature/test` to `master`
2. Start a build
3. Using the API (in a script), grab all open merge requests from the current project using `CI_PROJECT_ID` variable, and filter by `source_branch` and `target_branch`.
4. If there is a merge request open with the `source_branch` and `target_branch` being `feature/test` and `master` respectively, continue with the build, otherwise just skip the rest of the build.

For using the API, I don't believe you can use the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` variable to authenticate, so you'll probably need to create your own [personal access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) and store it as a [CI variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#variables) to use in the build job.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Another example, but using rules:

```
  rules:
    # pipeline should run on merge request to master branch
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == 'master'
      when: always
    # pipeline should run on merge request to release branch
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == 'release'
      when: always
    - when: never
```

Comment: `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == 'target'` would be sufficient since it would == '' if it weren't a merge request