# Only run GitLab CI job when target branch of a MR is a specific branch

Tags: gitlab-ci

I can run a job for a merge request like so:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script: ./test
  only:
  - merge_requests
```

However, I also only want to run this job if the target branch is a specific one (e.g. `master`). Is it possible to do this?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52746338/in-gitlab-ci-is-there-a-variable-for-a-merge-requests-target-branch

Answer (score 3):

Merge request where the target branch is **master**:

```
only:
    refs:
        - merge_requests
    variables:
        - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"
```

Comment: This worked for me, and should be the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only starting from Gitlab 11.6 according to the docs https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/

Comment: Which part of that answer my question? It's just about the `merge_requests` pipeline option in general which I already had working