# How to get target branch hash in GitLab CI community edition?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've tried using `only: [merge_request]` as per the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/merge_request_pipelines/pipelines_for_merged_results/index.html) to get `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_SHA` and `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_SHA`. Unfortunately `declare -x` shows that [these variables are set but *empty*](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/pacman-package-file/-/jobs/865188694) ([.gitlab-ci.yml file](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/pacman-package-file/-/blob/c9126464a7640ef145eaa38da2befe3611a8badd/.gitlab-ci.yml)). As far as I can tell, none of the `CI_` variables give this crucial information to work out the commit hash of the target branch.

I've also tried with `except: [master]`, with [similar results](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/pacman-package-file/-/jobs/865188385) ([.gitlab-ci.yml file](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/pacman-package-file/-/blob/776e37650a42c4bd3ce930df9daad57113292766/.gitlab-ci.yml)).

I've already looked at a [similar Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52746338/96588), so I wonder if this might be a regression.

As you can also see from the job output there are *no branches,* so I can't even use something like `master..HEAD`.

Comment: Can you post you complete `.gitlab-ci.yml`? Is the pipeline running in detached mode for the merge request?

Comment: @KiwiKilian I've linked to both versions of the file. As you can see from the output, the first CI run is detached (`CI_MERGE_REQUEST_EVENT_TYPE="detached"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It might actually be a bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/11295). I was very confident to have an example using the `SHA` variables in our codebase, but it suffers the same problem. A workaround I found for your job:

```yaml
lint commit messages:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
  script:
    - git fetch
    - poetry run gitlint --commits "origin/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}..origin/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME}"
```

I switched to the `rules` syntax, [GitLab recommends doing so](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic):

> The rules syntax is an improved, more powerful solution for defining when jobs should run or not. Consider using rules instead of only/except to get the most out of your pipelines.

Results in:

```
$ poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file
No dependencies to install or update
$ git fetch
From https://gitlab.com/KiwiKilian/pacman-package-file
 * [new branch]      lint       -> origin/lint
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
$ poetry run gitlint --commits "origin/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}..origin/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME}"
Commit 7c9f4e7c1a:
1: CT1 Title does not start with one of fix, feat, chore, docs, style, refactor, perf, test, revert, ci, build: "Ignore IDEA configuration"
1: CT1 Title does not follow ConventionalCommits.org format 'type(optional-scope): description': "Ignore IDEA configuration"
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: [First bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/288876)

Comment: [Second bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/288877)