# I want to trigger gitlab ci pipeline only when 1 of the below 2 conditions are met

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

I want to trigger gitlab ci pipeline only when 1 of the below 2 conditions are met.

- When PR get merged in main/master branch from any other branch.
  OR
- When commit message contains `BUILD_CONTAINER_IMAGE` string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a set of [workflow rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowrules):

- [using a variable for a Merge Request's target branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72306696/6309)
- [using commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71437930/6309)

That would be in your case:

```yaml
rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /BUILD_CONTAINER_IMAGE/'
      when: always
    # pipeline should run on merge request to master branch
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == 'master'
      when: always
    # pipeline should run on merge request to main branch
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == 'main'
      when: always
    - when: never
```